# Put Autoarima summary results in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, model, time-series, summary

I am running several regression models and desire to have the results in a data frame. I tried several methods they have been unsuccessful.

```
Series <- ts(DATA[,2],start = c(2012,9), end = c(2019,6),frequency = 12)
model1 <- auto.arima(Series)
```

The result is:

```
Series: Series 
ARIMA(3,0,0)(0,1,1)[12] with drift 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2     ar3     sma1   drift
      0.4960  0.0948  0.2315  -0.7907  -1e-04
s.e.  0.1279  0.1377  0.1330   0.3010   2e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 6.651e-06:  log likelihood=314.61
AIC=-617.22   AICc=-615.89   BIC=-603.73
```

I am using this code:

```
A <- data.frame(unclass(summary(model1)), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I only get:

```
Training set error measures:
                      ME        RMSE         MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 6.24861e-05 0.002296059 0.001623711 -0.1866752 5.835606 0.4495353 -0.0191717
```

Comment: Look into the fable package

Comment: Also please provide some example data, look into the dput function